# CMake add target for invoking clang analyzer

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I'd basically like to achieve the same as http://blog.alexrp.com/2013/09/26/clangs-static-analyzer-and-automake, but with CMake.

```
analyze_srcs = foo.c
analyze_plists = $(analyze_srcs:%.c=%.plist)
CLEANFILES = $(analyze_plists)

$(analyze_plists): %.plist: %.c
  @echo "  CCSA  " $@
  @$(COMPILE) --analyze $< -o $@

analyze: $(analyze_plists)
.PHONY: analyze
```

So you can run

```
make analyze
make clean
```

I guess I need to use `add_custom_command/add_custom_target` and somehow change the "object file" extension just for that target.

Afterwards get a list of the generated files to perhaps pass them to a script for combining them into 1 output file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way:

```php
function(add_clang_static_analysis target)
    get_target_property(SRCs ${target} SOURCES)
    add_library(${target}_analyze OBJECT EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${SRCs})
    set_target_properties(${target}_analyze PROPERTIES
                          COMPILE_OPTIONS "--analyze"
                          EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD true)
endfunction()
```

Combining clang's plist files (which get extension .o this way) into a report is still open (`$<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlibtarget>`?).

Comment: The build fails because of missing compilation flags (like `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, `DEFINITIONS`), that are not copied from the source `target`.

Comment: True, you'd need to copy the whole target basically.

Answer (score 34):

You can use `scan-build` when running `cmake`.

```
scan-build cmake /path/to/source
scan-build make
```

`scan-build` sets the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables which are picked up by `cmake`.

Comment: And remember to erase the CMake cache beforehand (otherwise the command will have no effect)

Comment: If you use a custom toolchain file, I'm not sure this works.

Comment: Which requires its own build rather than being a part of the normal build as a separate target. And it's a perl script.

Answer (score 6):

The following solution has the drawback of compiling and analyzing the entire project, not the specific targets.

```
set(on_side_build_path ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/clang_static_analysis)
set(scan_build_path scan-build)
set(reports_path ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/clang_static_analysis_reports)

# Creates clean directory where the analysis will be built.
add_custom_target(clang_static_analysis_prepare
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rm -rf ${on_side_build_path}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${on_side_build_path}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)

# Runs the analysis from the path created specifically for that task. Use 'my own' project source directory as the source directory.
add_custom_target(clang_static_analysis
    # scan-build wants Debug build, for better analysis.
    COMMAND ${scan_build_path} ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
    COMMAND ${scan_build_path}
                -v -v -o ${reports_path} 
                ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${on_side_build_path}
)

# Run the *_prepare target always before the analysis
add_dependencies(clang_static_analysis clang_static_analysis_prepare)
```

Invoke it with:

```
cmake --build . --target clang_static_analysis
```

## Bonus #1: Allowing custom toolchains to work

`scan-build` injects the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to specify the replaced compilers, which are `ccc-analyzer` and `c++-analyzer`. When defining `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` the `CC` and `CXX` variables will be ignored. What you need to do to support `scan-build` is to point `CMAKE_C*_COMPILER` variables to use the one from environment, if defined. So having that in your toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER some/path/to/c_compiler)
set(CMAKE_Cxx_COMPILER some/path/to/cxx_compiler)
```

Replace it with:

```
if(DEFINED ENV{CC})
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER $ENV{CC})
else()
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER some/path/to/c_compiler)
endif()

if(DEFINED ENV{CXX})
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER $ENV{CXX})
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER some/path/to/cxx_compiler)
endif()
```

## Bonus #2: Using scan-build from the LLVM toolchain

If your custom toolchain is LLVM, then most probably you want to use the `scan-build` command from the toolchain. To enable it, simply define the path to toolchain path using cmake's cache variables:

```
set(LLVM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH "some/path/here" CACHE PATH "Path to the LLVM toolchain")
```

or from the command line:

```
cmake -DLLVM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH=some/path/here ...
```

and then reuse the path from the custom target:

```
set(scan_build_path ${LLVM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/bin/scan-build)
```

## Bonus #3: Adding test command

**Note**: `enable_testing` shall be called before `add_test`. `enable_testing()` must be called from the project's top level `CMakeLists.txt` for `ctest` to resolve paths to tests.

```
add_test(
    NAME clang_static_analysis
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target clang_static_analysis
)
```

Run it like that:

```
# Fire configure and generate stages
cmake ../source/dir
ctest -R clang_static_analysis --verbose
```