# Can clang static analyzer (scan-build) be used with cmake --build?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang++, clang-static-analyzer

I'd like to use the clang static analyzer command line tool [`scan-build`](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html) with the convenience of [`cmake --build`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode).

[Most](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21785566/1398841) of the [resources](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2014/04/install-use-clang-static-analyzer-cmake.html) I found online seem to indicate you need a two-step process:

```
scan-build cmake .
scan-build make
```

For example for this small example program with a bug that `scan-build` catches:

```
#include <iostream>

int fun() {
    int x;
    return x; # main.cpp:5:5: warning: Undefined or garbage value returned to caller

}

int main() {
    int a = fun();

    std::cout << "Hello, World! " << a << std::endl;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test_program)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(test_program ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

If I run `scan-build cmake --build cmake-build-release/` it does not find the bug, even though the binary is built. Is there anyway to get `scan-build` to work in a one step process with CMake?

Comment: You could probably get what you want by using a custom target and using `clang --build <dir> --target <tgt>`. But why waste your time? Just use a wrapper around the two `scan-build` steps.

Comment: I also like `cmake --build` because it keeps all of the generated files nicely tucked away in a folder rather than putting them all in the root of the project.

Comment: you have control over that too w/o using `--build`. i keep my source and build directories side-by-side. then you can just do `cd myproj/build; cmake ../src/`

Comment: You should anyway use out-of-source builds. Having files in your source directory isn't a good argument.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the Clang Static Analyzer, you should just set `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=YES`. This will create a *compilation database* that CSA can read. You don't even need to build your project. The file is located at: `/path/to/build/compile_commands.json`.

`scan-build` is designed for projects that can't create a compilation database themselves.

Then you can run:

```
analyze-build --cdb /path/to/build/compile_commands.json \
              --use-analyzer /path/to/clang \
              --output /path/to/output
```

It's worth noting that `clang-tidy` has all of the CSA checks now. You can use this same compilation database technique to run `clang-tidy` on your codebase.